# Bibliotecas e pré-processamento em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, compilação, biblioteca

Sempre estranhei a sintaxe do `#include` e do `#define`, pois diferem muito da sintaxe do restante da linguagem. Descobri que isso se deve ao fato desses comandos se destinarem ao pré-processador e não ao processo de compilação "em si".

Descobri também que manuais de compiladores como o [Manual do GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) desestimulam o uso do pré-processador, sugerindo que o programador dê preferência aos mecanismos da própria linguagem. Exemplo: na [seção](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html#Pragmas) sobre o comando `#pragma`, que modifica os parâmetros para compilação, recomenda-se sempre que possível substituí-lo por atributos de função.

Entretanto, apesar dos argumentos para dar-se preferência ao compilador me pareçam coerentes, nunca encontrei uma forma de usar bibliotecas em C/C++ sem o comando de  pré-processamento `#include`. Além disso, para evitar a inclusão de cabeçalhos duplicados, é necessário utilizar [*include guards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) ou o comando `#pragma once`, ambos dependentes do pré-processador.

Porque as linguagens C/C++ não dão suporte à inclusão de bibliotecas utilizando apenas comandos do compilador?

Em Pascal e Object Pascal temos o `uses`, em C# `using`e em Java o `import`, entre outros exemplos. Sei que as linguagens C/C++ estão em constante desenvolvimento e atualização até hoje, então por que esse tipo de recurso nunca foi adicionado?

Eu compreendo a utilização do pré-processador para compilação condicional, em especial no desenvolvimento de funções compatíveis entre vários SOs. Mas usar bibliotecas não seria uma função muito básica para ficar a cargo do pré-processador? Qual a justificativa para isso?

Desde que estudei o assunto, sinto que sempre que uso bibliotecas em C/C++ estou fazendo uma "gambiarra".

Answer (score 4):

Sem o `#include` realmente fica bem complicado, ainda que possível. Não sei se falam pra não usar nem isso, imagino que falam de outras coisas.

> Porque as linguagens C/C++ não dão suporte à inclusão de bibliotecas utilizando apenas comandos do compilador?

Porque C foi criada há quase 50 anos atrás e isto não era tão simples, não pensaram nisso bem. C++ precisou manter a compatibilidade.

> Em Pascal e Object Pascal temos o uses

No início não tinha nada disso.

C muda pouco, a ideia é mantê-la estável. C++ terá algo assim logo, mas não sei se eliminará totalmente o uso do PP.

> Eu compreendo a utilização do pré-processador para compilação condicional

Em C++ já podia em grande parte, e logo poderá em 100% casos não precisa disso.

> usar bibliotecas não seria uma função muito básica para ficar a cargo do pré-processador? Qual a justificativa para isso?

Não é nada trivial inserir na linguagem, é trivial em C porque não faz parte da linguagem, e por consequência não dá muitas garantias, se você fizer errado, babau.